# Rails 3.1: Is there any way I can view which indexes have been created for my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having a problem with my ActiveRecord exception handling and I suspect some of the indexes haven't been created as I thought they did.  How can I view the indexes that have been created for my model?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Database indices? What database?

Comment: Some versions of activerecord (I forget which) fail silently if the length of the  index name is greater than what the db allows (64 for MySQL I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just look in your `db/schema.rb` where all the structure of the database is explicitly listed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MySQL, from your command line:

```
     $ rails dbconsole
mysql> show create table users;

users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Any "KEY" lines are your indexes.